# SQL Server xls file returns first row values incorrectly or skips it

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssms

I'm having a problem when trying to import a .xls Excel file to create a new table in SQL Server Management Studio. The thing is that I have the column titles in the first row, but if I check "First row has column names", when I go to "edit mappings" the column titles are actually the values that start from the 2nd row. If I uncheck "First row has column names", then the column names are "F1, F2, F3, F4" and so on.

The .xls file is `microsoft sql 97-2004 worksheet` and I already specified that on the import wizard.

Are there any solutions? Can it be a problem with the .xls file?

Comment: Upload a sample file, only the first lines to Google Drive and share the link

Comment: "Microsoft Excel 97-2004 worksheet" files? BIFF (Binary Interchange File Format) hasn't been a default format since Office 2003. Is there some reason you're not using the modern OOXML (Office Open XML) files with the `.xlsx` extension?